# Active sub menus in Wordpress CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, css-selectors, parent-child

I have problem with sub menus in Wordpress website, I was reading a lot and trying to fix it but I didnt make it.

There is a navigation menu

```
Primary menu:

      1.

      2.

        a) (sub menu)

           I.   ( sub sub menu)

           II.  ( sub sub menu)

        b) (sub menu)

           I.  ( sub sub menu)

           II. ( sub sub menu)

      3.
```

Menu is working untill I go to `sub sub menu` and then the problem come out, menu just show to `sub menu` and all   `sub sub menus` dissapear. I am asking for help, any suggestions? I understand that there may be a problem with `display` somewhere in a CSS, but I can't find where.

Link to website http://www.unumdesign.uk/kensington-collection/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set css on hover state like following way:

```
li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

and for sub sub menus,

```
li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```